# Can one read an XML response as a stream in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, extjs, streaming

I have a request that generates an XML response.  Due to certain present constraints the response can be quite slow to complete but does begin to return data quickly.

Is it possible to read the response stream in Ext JS before the response is complete?  My understanding is that `*Readers` are only given the response text once it is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an Ext.Proxy for [Comet techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), and I think one would be pretty tough to write. First of all, you'll need to write a Sax parser to make any sense of an incomplete XML document. Then, you'll need to write a proxy that repeatedly executes Operations when new data comes through. ExtJS isn't really designed for this, but it'd be an interesting thing to try. I'm not sure how practical it would be, though; any implemented Ext.Proxy would behave very differently from the other Proxies; though it might have methods with the same names, it'd be a very different interface. You'd have to extend Ext.Model and Ext.Store to understand how to populate themselves with streamed data, writing new listeners for chunk events and new data contracts for the consumers of Stores and Models. I'm not sure it'd be worth your time!

However, if all you need is an event to be thrown when a stream chunk comes through, then that's possible in Gecko and WebKit browsers. You just need to attach a handler to the onreadystate event of the XHR, which will fire every time data is received.

Experimentally:

```
Ext.define('Ext.proxy.StreamEventedAjax',{
    extend: 'Ext.proxy.Ajax',
    doRequest: function(operation, callback, scope) {

        if (Ext.isIE) return null;

        // do other doRequest setup here, use this.buildRequest, etc

        var me = this,
            req = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            responseLength = 0,
            newText = "";
        req.onreadystate = function(e) {

           newText = req.responseText.substring(responseLength);
           responseLength = req.responseText.length;

           operation.fireEvent('datareceived',e,newText);

        }

        req.open(me.getMethod(request),request.url);

    }
});
```

Comment: Cheers @zetlen, you're right this isn't worth my time, but am accepting your answer as it is a good pointer as to how to go about solving the problem.